# changing a forms recordsource depending on booking date in ms access

Tags: forms, ms-access

Is there a way to change a forms recordsource depending on the date. e.g. If the booking date was made before 08/08/2013 use this view, otherwise use the new view?

Answer (score 0):

In the combobox you use for selecting the booking you can change the `RecordSource` property

Example:

```
Private Sub combo_AfterUpdate()
    Me.RecordSource = "NewQuery"
    Me.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply but my form dosent use a combobox for the booking date. It's a form that displays everything in fields. I recently made some relationship changes to the old view (because it was creating duplicates) and because of that the description for the room booking does not display anymore for the old records. Is there a fix for this?